# Can I give custom voice commands to Google Glass to perform actions related to my Glassware?

Tags: google-mirror-api, google-glass

I want to give custom voice commands to Glass to perform actions like 'next page' or 'delete' or any other custom commands. Can I develop an app to accept my custom voice commands? If so please help me with a reference or example or tutorial.

Comment: Off-topic for StackOverflow. See [on-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Take a look at the Google documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Glass team is working on this. The team has already accepted a [feature request](https://code.google.com/p/google-glass-api/issues/detail?id=6&q=voice%20command&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Priority%20Owner%20Component%20Summary) for what you describe. Watch the [Glass documentation](https://developers.google.com/glass/) for an update in the future and try asking something more specific when the feature does come out.

Comment: Thank you for responding. Looking forward to this feature eagerly.